# Construct XML Request for RESTful WCF C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying create RESTful WCF Service. I want the XML on Service.svc as below

```
<Organization>
<Employees>
<Employee>Test1</Employee>
<Employee>Test2</Employee>
</Employees>
</Organization>
```

I want to create the XML as above structure using WCF C# Class Properties

Here's what I tried below

```
Public class Organization
{
   Public List<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
}

Public class Employee
{
  Public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong.

Comment: You can’t do this. Every DataMember has a name attribute. If you don’t set it, its default value is the name of the target to which the attribute is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `DataContract` attribute, and the corresponding `DataMember` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?view=netcore-3.1

Example:

```
namespace MyTypes
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PurchaseOrder
    {
        private int poId_value;

        // Apply the DataMemberAttribute to the property.
        [DataMember]
        public int PurchaseOrderId
        {

            get { return poId_value; }
            set { poId_value = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Or in your case:

```
[DataContract]
Public class Organization
{
   [DataMember]
   Public List<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
Public class Employee
{
  [DataMember]
  Public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

This will add an extra node called name in your XML though. If you want the exact format as you defined, then remove the `Employee` class and declare the list as a list of strings like this:

```
[DataContract]
Public class Organization
{
   [DataMember]
   Public Employees Employees {get;set;}
}
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName="Employee")]
public class  Employees: List<string>  {}
```

Comment: I don't want to add Name node. How can I just have list of employee inside employees tag

Comment: So it should be `<Employees><Employee>Test1</Employee><Employee>Test2</Employee></Employees>`

Comment: See the updated version with the `CollectionDataContract` attribute